# How to run jquery function after the animation has completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

so i'm new to javascript and jquery. Need some help on how to run the 2nd function after the 1st one has completed?
The first function is a progress bar and the second one is a form that i want to fade in after the progressbar animation completed.

The script:

```js
$(function() {
  var msecsPerUpdate = 1000 / 60; // # of milliseconds between updates, this gives 60fps
  var progress = $('progress');
  var duration = 1; // secs to animate for
  var interval = progress.attr('max') / (duration * 1000 / msecsPerUpdate);

  var animator = function() {
    progress.val(progress.val() + interval);
    if (progress.val() + interval < progress.attr('max')) {
      setTimeout(animator, msecsPerUpdate);
    } else {
      progress.val(progress.attr('max'));
    }
  }

  $('a#forgot').click(animator);
});

$(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('generator#forgot').css('bottom', '5px');
  $(this).fadeOut('medium', function() {
    $('a#back').fadeIn();
  });

});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post a jsFiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a callback function to your `animator` function to make it look like this:

```
var animator = function(callback) {
  progress.val(progress.val() + interval);
  if (progress.val() + interval < progress.attr('max')) {
    setTimeout(animator, msecsPerUpdate);
  } else {
    progress.val(progress.attr('max'));
    callback();
  }
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
$('a#forgot').click(function() {
  animator(function() {
    console.log('this runs after your animation has completed');
  }); 
});
```

Note: this is a simplified code-snippet without params or error handling, which you might wanna add.